# Adding a mac-like theme/skin to Ubuntu

Tags: themes, mac, customization

I am very fond of macbooks so I wanted to revamp my Ubuntu to look like a mac desktop.

Please suggest a suitable theme/skin with minimum bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can make your Ubuntu look exactly like OS X.**

Some screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Just add the [Macbuntu PPA](https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/macbuntu)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/macbuntu
sudo apt-get update
```

and install the following packages.

- For themes, icons and cursors

  ```
  sudo apt-get install macbuntu-os-icons-lts-v7 macbuntu-os-ithemes-lts-v7
  ```
- To install Slingscold Launcher

  ```
  sudo apt-get install slingscold
  ```
- For Spotlight

  ```
  sudo apt-get install albert
  ```
- For Plank dock

  ```
  sudo apt-get install plank macbuntu-os-plank-theme-lts-v7
  ```

Finally install some tweak tools to select mac theme:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool gnome-tweak-tool
```

And for final touch install [these mac wallpapers](http://drive.noobslab.com/data/Mac/MacBuntu-Wallpapers.zip).

Done.