# Installing GNOME themes on Unity

Tags: themes

I've got Mac theme but it's for only GNOME desktops. I use Ubuntu 16.04 which is Unity desktop. Can I install that theme?

Comment: You might want to install the [gnome desktop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/614657/install-gnome-desktop-ubuntu-15-04) first

Comment: do i have to do it first?

Comment: Install mac theme on unity desktop       http://askubuntu.com/questions/861700/adding-a-mac-like-theme-skin-to-ubuntu/861705#861705

Comment: Is this a gtk or gnome shell theme?

Comment: I would assume that since it's a gnome theme, it would have dependencies on the gnome desktop.