# Not able to apply macbuntu theme

Tags: apt, software-installation, 16.10, macbuntu

I just started using Ubuntu so please give me an explained answer.

I was trying to install macbuntu theme in my Ubuntu 16.10.
I did the first step which was

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/macbuntu
```

This step worked fine. Next when I did,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I got the error

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/docky-core/stable/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/docky-core/stable/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

These are just the last few lines which gives the error.

How do I solve this?

EDIT : This is the contents of the `sources.list.d` directory

```
    docky-core-ubuntu-stable-yakkety.list
    docky-core-ubuntu-stable-yakkety.list.save
    noobslab-ubuntu-macbuntu-yakkety.list
    noobslab-ubuntu-macbuntu-yakkety.list.save
    webupd8team-ubuntu-java-yakkety.list
    webupd8team-ubuntu-java-yakkety.list.save
    webupd8team-ubuntu-sublime-text-3-yakkety.list
    webupd8team-ubuntu-sublime-text-3-yakkety.list.save
```

Output of `lsb_release -a command`

```
    No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 16.10
    Release:    16.10
    Codename:   yakkety
```

Comment: If i type the cat noobslab-ubuntu-macbuntu-yakkety.list , it says no such directory or file found

Comment: Here's the problem, as Pilot6 said, your system is 16.10 not 16.04.

Comment: And 16.10 is not supported by this PPA.

Comment: So what do I do now to install the theme? Are there seperate commands for 16.10 version ?

Comment: there's a work around you can try, I'll write an answer and see if it works..

Comment: noobslab have a pack for 16.10 too. but even that doesnt work

Comment: [http://www.noobslab.com/2016/11/macbuntu-1610-transformation-pack-for.html] Check this link for that

Comment: Then you are in the correct repository. Try upgrading your system.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps

```
 cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

 sudo -H gedit noobslab-ubuntu-macbuntu-yakkety.list
```

A file will open and first line will be something like this

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/macbuntu/ubuntu yakkety main
```

replace `yakkety` with `xenial` so that this line becomes

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/macbuntu/ubuntu xenial main
```

save and exit the file and

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now try to install `mac theme` using this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861700/adding-a-mac-like-theme-skin-to-ubuntu/861705#861705)

**For removing mac theme:**

In case installing mac theme is not supported by your system, uninstall using:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:noobslab/macbuntu
sudo apt-get update
```

## OR

```
sudo apt-add-repository remove ppa:noobslab/macbuntu
```

Comment: This may work, but it may break the system as well.

Comment: It is showing as a read only file .How do i save the changes? And i have more than one entry here of the exact same code. Should I delete the rest.

Comment: @SriramR I fixed the command. But beware of consequences. This theme is not supposed to be used on 16.10.

Comment: @SriramR: You can always uninstall mac theme if it does something nasty to your systmem. And use command updated by Pilot6

Comment: Okay I will try this. Can you please give me the commands for uninstalling just in case something happens?

Comment: @SriramR: see updated answer

Comment: @Rahul I think `ppa-purge` is a better choice, since it will restore some replaced  packages. Only `purge` may not be good enough.

Comment: I have chaged yakkety to xenial . It still doesnt work .Dammit. I have given up :(

Comment: @SriramR That was initially not a great idea to install 16.10 for a newbie. Install 16.04 LTS.

Comment: @SriramR: What error message you are getting. And you should listen to Pilot6's last comment, 16.04 is better choice for you.

Comment: Yeah I'm gonna install 16.04LTS now. I thought I was installing 16.10 tho . Is it enough if I go into my Windows 10 and delete the partition which has linux to remove this 16.10 version?